# LG G3 Host File

Tags: root-access, lg-g3

I recently rooted my android LG g3 phone and started experiencing problems with the Google Play Store and was getting errors like 495 and such and have been unable to download any new apps or games.   I then went a researched on how to fix this, and found several YouTube videos that suggested deleting all lines in the host file except for "127.0.0.1 local host." I did that but am still unable to download apps. I then researched and removed my Google account and then tried to resign in or whatever, but got errors there like "unable to reach Google server." I finally had to do a factory reset to get my Google account back on, but am still having the same errors in the play store.   What should I do?  My host file now reads:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
#127.22.3.134 android.clients.google.com
talk.google.com
```

(That last line starting with the hash tag was an idea from an article I read but didn't seem to help.)

Thanks guys!!
Davy

Answer (score 1):

The line with the "#" is a comment and isn't doing anything.

The line after that is not formatted correctly.

The format of the `hosts` file is

```
    IPADDRESS    HOSTNAME
```

The point of the `hosts` file is so the device does not have to ask a [DNS Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) what the IP Address of a host is.

You may be getting that error because it finds the host name in your hosts file, but there is not an IP address to go along with it.